# How to use the $compile, or make work the ng-click on dynamically generated button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable

I've been working with angular and jquery datatable, the thing is that I want to use ng-click with the buttons rendered by the datatable, the thing is that when I click on them nothing happens, I've been researching about it and found out that I have to use The $compile of angular, but I don't know how to use it in this particular case(or any), could somebody tell me how to make work the angular ng click on dynamic generated DOM, thanks , 
pd. this is the code of my table, meanwhile I'm using the Onclick function, and it works but when I click it the window location changes to the main page and I don't want, that . thx

```
$('#sr_list').dataTable({
    "sDom" : "<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",
    "aLengthMenu": [
                        [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
                        [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] // change per page values here
                    ],
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "sAjaxSource": ng.api +"/srs/list",
    "aoColumns":[
            {"mData": "srBol"},
            {"mData": "trip"},
            {"mData": "shipper"},
            //{"mData": "truck"},
            {"mData": "consignee"},
            {"mData": "trailer"},

            //{"mData": "carrier"},
            {"mData": "reqDate"},
            //{"mData": "delDate"},
            {"mData": "status"},                     
            {"fnRender": function(oObj){
                    //console.log(oObj.aData);
                var i=0,
                    link = 'reports/bol.php?bol='+oObj.aData.srBol+'',
                    bolBtn = '<a href="#" onClick= window.open("'+link+'") data-id="'+oObj.aData.srBol+'" class="btn btn-xs blue btn-bol"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> BoL</a>',
                    filediv = '<div class="btn-group"><button class="btn default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Files..<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button><ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu"><li><span data-id="'+oObj.aData.srBol+'" class="btn btn-xs green btn-addfile fileinput-button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span> File</span><input type="file" id="fileselect" data-id="'+oObj.aData.srBol+'" class="input-addfile" name="files[]" multiple="multiple"></span>',
                    file = "",
                    open= "";

                    while(i < oObj.aData.files.length){
                        var link = "uploads/"+oObj.aData.files[i],
                            open = 'onClick=window.open("'+link+'"")';
                            file = file +'<li><a href="#" '+open+' >'+oObj.aData.files[i]+'</a></li>';
                            i++;
                    }
                    var fileBtn = filediv+file+'</ul></div>';

                    if((oObj.aData.trip > 0) && (oObj.aData.statusviaje === "19")){
                        link = 'mapa.php?viaje='+oObj.aData.trip+'';
                        open = 'onClick=window.open("'+link+'")';
                        //console.log(open);
                        mapBtn = '<a href="#" '+open+' data-id="'+oObj.aData.trip+'" class="btn btn-xs yellow btn-map"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Map </a>';
                        return(bolBtn + fileBtn + mapBtn);
                    }
                    else{
                        return(bolBtn + fileBtn); 
                    }    
                }       
            }                                                                                                                               

    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap_full_number",
    "aoColumnDefs": [   
                        {   
                            'bSortable': true,
                            "mData": null,
                            "sDefaultContent": "Edit",
                            "aTargets": [ -1 ]
                        }
                    ]                

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You inject the compile method into your controller like so:

```
myCtrl($scope,$compile) {
   //you then compile the html html with the ng-click attribute on it and inject it into the DOM

   $scope.someAjaxCall = function(data) {
  //pretend i got some data back here and it's a button
  var button = $(data);
  $compile(button)($scope);

  // append your button where it needs to go
  $('body').append(button);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok man, it works when I append it to the body, but in this case you know to what I have to append it? ,please, thx for your help

Comment: I don't have enough context for you project to answer that for you. I have no idea how to get or what element you need to append the data to but it should be very easy for you to figure. If you really want me to help you figure that out you'll need to provide more context and information about your product.